# Why does javascript give these variables as objects in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to pass some variables to a PHP file in order to run an SQL query. However JavaScript is passing these variables as objects. Why is this happening? How can I change that?

```
  <?php include 'dbconfig.php';?>
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUCLIC "-//W3C//DTDHTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>LIBRARY DATABASE</TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mytable.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquerycss.css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () { 

            var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
            var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
            var memberID = dlg.find(("#memberID")),
            MFirst = dlg.find(("#MFirst")),
            MLast = dlg.find(("#Mlast")),
            Street = dlg.find(("#Street")),
            number = dlg.find(("#number")),
            postalCode = dlg.find(("#postalCode")),
            Mbirthdate = dlg.find(("#Mbirthdate"));
                type = type || 'Create';
                var config = {
                    autoOpen: true,
                    height: 500,
                    width: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create an account": save_data,
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        dlg.remove();
                    }
                };
                if (type === 'Edit') {
                    config.title = "Edit User";
                    get_data();
                    delete (config.buttons['Create an account']);
                    config.buttons['Edit account'] = function () {
                        window.open("edituple.php?memberID="+ memberID +"&MFirst=" + MFirst +"&MLast=" + MLast +"&Street=" + Street
                        +"&number=" + number + "&postalCode=" + postalCode +"&Mbirthdate=" + Mbirthdate);
                        dlg.dialog("close");
                    }; 
                }
                dlg.dialog(config); 
                function get_data() {
                    var _memberID = $(row.children().get(1)).text(),
                     _MFirst = $(row.children().get(2)).text(),
                     _MLast = $(row.children().get(3)).text(),
                    _Street = $(row.children().get(4)).text(),
                    _number = $(row.children().get(5)).text(),
                    _postalCode = $(row.children().get(6)).text(),
                    _Mbirthdate = $(row.children().get(7)).text();
                    memberID.val(_memberID);
                    MFirst.val(_MFirst);
                    MLast.val(_MLast); 
                    Street.val(_Street);
                    number.val(_number); 
                    postalCode.val(_postalCode);
                    Mbirthdate.val(_Mbirthdate); 
                } 
                function save_data() {
                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + (fname.find("option:selected").text() + ' ').concat(lname.find("option:selected").text()) + "</td>" + "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                }
            }; 
            $(document).on('click', 'span.delete', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, 
        function () {
            // alert($(this).text());
            $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
        }); 
                return false;
            });
            $(document).on('click', 'td a.edit', function () {
                new_dialog('Edit', $(this).parents('tr'));
                return false;
            }); 
            $("#create-user").button().click(new_dialog); 
        });
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="navbar">
                <a href="mydatabase.php">Home</a>
                <a href="member_table.php">Member</a>
                <a href="book_table.php">Book</a>
                <a href="borrows_table.php">Borrows</a>
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <div class="navbar2">
                    <a href="insert.php">Insert</a>
                    <a href="update.php">Update</a>
                    <a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
                  </div>

    <TABLE class="minimalistBlack">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> memberID </th>
        <th> First Name </th>
        <th> Last Name </th>
        <th> Street </th>
        <th> Number </th>
        <th> Postal Code </th>
        <th> Birthdate </th>
        <th> Update </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
            $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","library");
            mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

            if ($conn -> connect_error){
                die("Conenction failed:". $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $sql="SELECT memberID,MFirst,MLast,Street,number,postalCode,Mbirthdate FROM member";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows>0){

                while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['memberID']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['MFirst']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['MLast']."</td>";    
                    echo "<td>".$row['Street']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row['number']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row['postalCode']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td>".$row['Mbirthdate']."</td>"; 
                    echo "<td><a class =\"edit\" href=\"\">Edit </a>
                     | <a href=\"deletefmtable.php?memberID=$row[memberID]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";  
                }
                echo "</TABLE>";
            }
            else { echo "0 result"; }
            $conn->close();
         ?>
    </TABLE>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user" style="display:none">

        <p class="validateTips">

            All form fields are required.</p>       

            <form>

        <fieldset>

            <label for="memberID">

                Member ID </label>

                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            <label for="MFirst">

                First Name</label>

                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />


            <label for="MLast">

                Last Name </label>

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            <label for="Street">

                Street </label>

            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            <label for="number">

             number </label>

            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            <label for="postalCode">

            Postal Code </label>

            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

            <label for="Mbirthdate">

            Birthdate </label>

            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

        </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The purpose of the code , is to display a table and have edit and delete on the side. Delete button works perfectly , however for edit I need to pass the variables mentioned above to a php file

Comment: You're passing across `MFirst` instead of `MFirst.val(_MFirst);`. And you really should be using camelCase for variable names.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I did what you said , but now the button does not redirect me to the other file

Comment: I've reverted your question to its original; completely changing your question just because you got a (vague and poorly written) answer won't help people solve your problem. So, what is `MFirst` here? Where do you assign something to this variable?

Comment: @miken32 First is the first name of the member that submits the php form , member ID is the primary key in sql

Comment: I'm not asking about what it represents. Somewhere in your code you have `var MFirst = ...`. What is it?

Comment: Also there are some serious problems with variable scope in this code.

Comment: @miken32   `var memberID = dlg.find(("#memberID")),
            MFirst = dlg.find(("#MFirst")),
            MLast = dlg.find(("#Mlast")),
            Street = dlg.find(("#Street")),
            number = dlg.find(("#number")),
            postalCode = dlg.find(("#postalCode")),
            Mbirthdate = dlg.find(("#Mbirthdate"));`

Comment: So `MFirst` is a jQuery object. What does the corresponding HTML look like? I hope you don't have multiple elements with the same ID, that's just asking for trouble. Edit your question to include additional info, rather than trying to put code in comments. (This is different than editing your question to rewrite your code wholesale.)

Comment: @miken32 sorry I am late , had to sleep . I am uploading the whole code of the file , please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I like a challenge. Starting from the top:

1. You want to avoid mixing your PHP and HTML as much as possible. Likewise for JavaScript. Ideally they're in separate files altogether, but we'll just separate them here. Do your work at the top, and limit yourself to display only code down below.
2. Always escape data for display in HTML. Use `htmlspecialchars()` for this.
3. This isn't 1999, you should be using a modern document type declaration. Modern HTML also means lowercase elements and no need for `type` attributes on the `<script>` elements.
4. Indent and space your code consistently. It will help you debug problems and find efficiencies.
5. Declare variables with `var` either before using them or when first used
6. You shouldn't be cloning this dialog. Just populate it with new values when clicked.
7. Here we start getting into your real issues. First, you're relying on global variables way too much. As one example, you set all these variables' values in a `get_data()` function. But that happens when the dialog is being set up, not when the button is pushed. This stuff needs to happen at the time the form is submitted. (But see #12.)
8. We can get rid of that `get_data()` function altogether and move its functionality to where it belongs, the click handler for the edit link.
9. Using `data-` attributes is a great way to pass data from PHP to your client-side script. You can set these attributes on the button and avoid clumsy DOM traversal, instead just use `$.data()`.
10. Anytime something is getting changed or created, use the POST action, not GET. As the name implies, GET is only for fetching resources and should not take actions that change data.
11. Why remove completely with the dialog with the `close` property? I assume you want to reuse it or you wouldn't have the results from the edit pop up in a new window.
12. There's no need to get JS involved in your form submission at all, if you aren't using Ajax; just let the form submit normally.
13. Be consistent with your code. Why does the delete button have an event handler in the HTML, when all the others are separate?
14. You weren't closing your `<tr>` elements, and you closed your `<table>` element twice.
15. All your form elements were named and ID'd incorrectly.

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
    $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","library");
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

    if ($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("Conenction failed:". $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="SELECT memberID, MFirst, MLast, Street, number, postalCode, Mbirthdate FROM member";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $data = [];
    while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $row);
    }
    $conn->close();

    // test data
    $data = [
        ["memberID"=>1, "MFirst"=>"John", "MLast"=>"Smith", "Street"=>"Main St", "number"=>"123", "postalCode"=>"K1A 1A1", "Mbirthdate"=>"1990-06-27"]
    ];
    header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LIBRARY DATABASE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mytable.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquerycss.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () { 
            var new_dialog = function (type) {
                var dlg = $("#dialog-form");
                type = type || 'Create';
                var config = {
                    autoOpen: true,
                    height: 500,
                    width: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create an account": function () {
                            $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + (fname.find("option:selected").text() + ' ').concat(lname.find("option:selected").text()) + "</td>" + "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            dlg.dialog("close");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                };
                if (type === 'Edit') {
                    config.title = "Edit User";
                    delete (config.buttons['Create an account']);
                    config.buttons['Edit account'] = function () {
                        // just let the form submit itself normally
                        $("#dialog-form form").submit();
                        dlg.dialog("close");
                    };
                }
                dlg.dialog(config); 
            }; 
            $(document).on('click', 'span.delete', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
                }); 
                return false;
            });
            $("a.edit").click(function () {
                // populate the values; we're getting all the info from
                // the data- attributes on the link itself
                // note JS makes them all lowercase
                $("#dialog-form input#memberID").val($(this).data("memberid"));
                $("#dialog-form input#MFirst").val($(this).data("mfirst"));
                $("#dialog-form input#MLast").val($(this).data("mlast"));
                $("#dialog-form input#Street").val($(this).data("street"));
                $("#dialog-form input#number").val($(this).data("number"));
                $("#dialog-form input#postalCode").val($(this).data("postalcode"));
                $("#dialog-form input#Mbirthdate").val($(this).data("mbirthdate"));
                new_dialog('Edit');
                return false;
            }); 
            $("a.delete").click(function() {
                return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
            });
            $("#create-user").button().click(function() {
                // just clear the values
                $("#dialog-form input").val("");
                new_dialog();
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="mydatabase.php">Home</a>
        <a href="member_table.php">Member</a>
        <a href="book_table.php">Book</a>
        <a href="borrows_table.php">Borrows</a>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="navbar2">
        <a href="insert.php">Insert</a>
        <a href="update.php">Update</a>
        <a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
    </div>

    <table class="minimalistBlack">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> memberID </th>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Street </th>
                <th> Number </th>
                <th> Postal Code </th>
                <th> Birthdate </th>
                <th> Update </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['memberID']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['MFirst']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['MLast']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Street']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['number']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['postalCode']?></td>
                <td><?=$row['Mbirthdate']?></td>
                <td>
                    <a
                        class ="edit"
                        href="#"
                        <?php foreach ($row as $k=>$v):?>
                        data-<?=$k?>="<?=$v?>"
                        <?php endforeach?>
                    >Edit</a> |
                    <a class="delete" href="deletefmtable.php?memberID=<?=$row['memberID']?>">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user" style="display:none">
        <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>
            <form method="post" action="edituple.php" target="_blank">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="memberID">Member ID </label>
                    <input type="text" name="memberID" id="memberID" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" readonly="readonly" />

                    <label for="MFirst">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="MFirst" id="MFirst" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    <label for="MLast">Last Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="MLast" id="MLast" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    <label for="Street">Street </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Street" id="Street" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    <label for="number">number </label>
                    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code </label>
                    <input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />

                    <label for="Mbirthdate">Birthdate </label>
                    <input type="text" name="Mbirthdate" id="Mbirthdate" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

All you'll need to do is allow for `edituple.php` to look at `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. And don't forget to use prepared statements for database updates! I'd strongly recommend use of PDO or a higher-level database API. mysqli is very verbose, it was really designed to build database APIs, not be used directly.

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript's JSON.stringify(your_variable) function before sending and on PHP side, use json_decode($_GET['data'])

your_variable should be an object, you shouldn't wrap them to   like code. Do something like this:

```
data = {
    var _memberID = $(row.children().get(1)).text(),
     _MFirst = $(row.children().get(2)).text(),
     _MLast = $(row.children().get(3)).text(),
    _Street = $(row.children().get(4)).text(),
    _number = $(row.children().get(5)).text(),
    _postalCode = $(row.children().get(6)).text(),
    _Mbirthdate = $(row.children().get(7)).text();
    memberID.val(_memberID);
    MFirst.val(_MFirst);
    MLast.val(_MLast); 
    Street.val(_Street);
    number.val(_number); 
    postalCode.val(_postalCode);
    Mbirthdate.val(_Mbirthdate); 
}
```

then pass this data (stringified string or header set as content-type: application/json) to php via ajax post, at php side json_decode the posted data as I mention above and you'll have an array of data to use in sql query.

Comment: Please see the edit on the post , I sense I am doing something wrong